# Unable to install GNOME Extensions on Pop!_OS 22.04

Tags: gnome-shell, pop-os

I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS with the GNOME version 42.5 on a X11 Framework Laptop.

In the Extensions Manager (Version 0.4.0) I can browse extensions and click on install but they won't install and will provide no feedback.

On extensions.gnome.org I can click on the on switch, it will prompt me to install the package but it won't really install it. On the website I see a banner telling me "Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6. Probably you should upgrade native host connector or install plugins for missing APIs. Refer documentation for instructions.". I have actually installed the `gnome-shell-extension-manager@0.3.0-0ubuntu2.1`, `gnome-shell-extensions@42.1-0ubuntu1`, `chrome-gnome-shell@10.1-5` but it still doesn't install the extensions.

I am kind of stuck. Any idea what could solve this? Any help is appreciated! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The following steps resolved it for me.

1. From a terminal, run `gnome-extensions-app`. This should open the settings screen for gnome extensions.

   [image: Screenshot of the gnome extension options]
2. Toggle `Extensions` to the on setting as pictured, which should enable extensions.
3. Try installing your extension at https://extensions.gnome.org.